# Explicit formula of biholomorphism between the rectangle and unit disk

Tags: cv.complex-variables

From the Riemann mapping theorem we know that there exists a biholomorphism between the rectangle $R$ and the unit disk $D$, can we write this biholomorphic map explicitly?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz%E2%80%93Christoffel_mapping

Comment: Ah, Emil beat me to it by 30 secs ;-) so deleting my previous comment!

Comment: (While the Wikipedia article presents a biholomorphism from a half-plane rather than from a disk, this is easy to fix with a Möbius transformation.)